# Permission denied trying to uninstall nose

Tags: python

I have been having a really hard time getting nose to installed properly on my mac. Many people on the site have had this problem in the past and I was following the instructions of past posts. In the terminal is shows that nose is installed and upgraded.

```
pip install nose
```

When I tried to uninstall nose I got this back:

Exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in
>   main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line
>   76, in run
>       requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 336, in
>   uninstall
>       req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742,
>   in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line
>   115, in remove
>       renames(path, new_path)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 267,
>   in renames
>       shutil.move(old, new)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py",
>   line 303, in move
>       os.unlink(src) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.7.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'

What can I do to get nose installed properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If permission is denied, then you should try uninstalling it with super-user privileges. That is, run `sudo pip uninstall nose`.

Comment: Thank you for response! I am new and a little shy about sudo. I decided to use virtualenv and that worked perfect.